# Set a getter using => C#

Tags: c#, getter

Can I simplify this...

```cs
public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public override Valor Nome
    {
        get
        {
            return new Valor
            {
                ValorEntrada = "agência centro"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

...to something like this?

```cs
public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public override Valor Nome => Valor.ValorEntrada = "agência centro";
}
```

`Valor` has  a property called `ValorEntrada` which receives a `string`.

Comment: What is the definition of `Valor` and why doesn't it have a primary-constructor? Why is it mutable?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel `public override Valor Test => Valor.ValorEntrada = "Value";` is not valid (even if `Valor` is a valid identifier in this context, the result of `=` here is a `String` value and not a `Valor` reference.

Comment: It's very dubious to have a getter return a new instance on every call. Consider carefully if that's really what you're after, or rather a one-time initialization.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Depends on what is being constructed and returned. Allocations are cheap in C#. It's side effects you need to watch out for.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: Yes, allocations are (usually) cheap. Garbage collection is not. And there's always the issue of whether object identity is important (which can also be considered a "side effect", I suppose). This is by no means always wrong, but it *is* dubious.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel one of those weird side effects: `yourObject.Test != yourObject.Test`

Comment: Look at the [with](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#nondestructive-mutation) keyword and how it can mutate a value safely.

Comment: @JAlex AFAIK the `with` operator only works with `record` types, not general `class` and `struct` types, unfortunately. C# 10 does support using `with` with anonymous-types, but anonymous-types are otherwise completely horrible and should not be used, imo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. But you still need the `new` operator with an object-initializer...

```
public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public override Valor Nome => new Valor { ValorEntrada = "agência centro" };
}
```

**...however** that is a bad design.

- Assuming that your `Valor` type is a `class` rather than a `struct`, then returning `new Valor` in a property-getter means potentially unnecessary managed-heap object allocations.

  - While allocations are "cheap" (I wouldn't personally say that), the cost of GC isn't.
  - In .NET, property-getters should always be both side-effect-free and always safe to use regardless of the state of the containing object. While there's nothing in the example code which seems to have side-effects, it *does* break caller's expectations about *object identity*.
  - For example, this is how the property will behave, and I'd argue this violates expectations:

    ```
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Valor v1 = foo.Nome;
    Valor v2 = foo.Nome;
    Console.WriteLine( Object.ReferenceEquals( v1, v2 ) ); // "False"
    ```
- The fact you're using an object-initializer to set what looks like a *required* property instead of passing the `"agência centro"` string via a constructor parameter suggests that your `Valor` class is mutable.

  - Which is bad, given the points above.
  - Because it means this will happen:

    ```
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.Nome.ValorEntrada = "x";
    Console.WriteLine( foo.Nome.ValorEntrada ); // This prints "agência centro" instead of "x"
    ```

### Better alternatives:

A better solution depends on what exactly your `Valor` class represents, and what the `Nome` property is meant to do.

- If the parent class is intended as a factory then you should use a method, not a property, that way you're not breaking any assumptions or *implied contracts* imposed by using a property:

  ```
  public Valor CreateNewValor() => new Valor { ValorEntrada = "agência centro" };
  ```
- If the `Valor` type should be immutable then you should populate it using a constructor and store it in a readonly field (or readonly auto-property). It will most likely also be appropriate to use a `static` field as there's no point having multiple copies of identical immutable objects:

  ```
  private static readonly Valor _instance = new Valor( valorEntrada: "agência centro" );

  public override Valor Nome => _instance;
  ```